# jquery .on() context of this when delegating

Tags: jquery, binding, delegates, this, bind

I am using the delegate functionality of the `.on()` bind event in jQuery 1.7.2 and of course the context of `this` is the delegated selector, and not the element where the event is triggered from. I need to access `this` from the element that's being clicked on. I know I could just search for it using `this` of the delegated (parent) selector, but there must be a cleaner way.

```
$('#wrap').on('click', 'button', function(){
    console.log($(this)) //returns #wrap, not button
});
```

## Clarification

The issue was that I was passing a jQuery object as the second parameter, see example

http://jsfiddle.net/RobertSheaO/yVbZe/

Comment: It should return `button`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/eF3W9/

Comment: I call BS. http://jsfiddle.net/vrPDv/

Comment: Are you sure? I'm on 1.7.2 and did the exact same thing. No problem.

Comment: I'm investigating why this is so. I see in your examples it works, but in mine it doesn't. I'll check in in a few minutes.

Comment: Perhaps because as delegate implies, the button doesn't exist until later. See my example for proof of it returning the delegated container, and not the button. http://jsfiddle.net/RobertSheaO/yVbZe/

Comment: You can't put a jQuery object as the second argument to `.on`, it has to be a string, like in the question.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, that was the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fiddle is different from the question, and that difference is significant. In the fiddle you wrote:

```
var wrap  =  jQuery('#wrap'),
    removeButton = jQuery('button');

wrap.on('click', removeButton, function(){    
    console.log(jQuery(this));
});
```

The problem is that `removeButton` is an empty jQuery collection, because the button doesn't exist when that assignment is performed.

When delegating with `.on()` to elements that get added dynamically, you *must* supply a string as the selector argument.